# A simple calculus implying convexity that I cannot see

Tags: calculus

I have data that are $x_1,..., x_t,..., x_T$, with $T$ finite.

I am supposed to compare $T \overline{x}^2$ and $\sum x_t^2$.

I guess I can use Jensen's inequality with the function $u:x->x^2$, then

$(\sum \dfrac{1}{T} x_t)^2 \leq \sum \frac{1}{T} x_t^2 $

But I am supposed to explain it for people that are not familiar with it, and I have been failing at proving it with basic arithmetic for nearly one hour, so I would appreciate some help !

Thenk you in advance.

Comment: What is $\;T\;$ , what is $\;x\;$, what is $\;x_t\;$, is the sum finite?

Comment: Edited to be more precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I. Bare-hands proof.

1. The result is clearly true (I use $y$'s instead of $x$'s) if $\mu_y := \sum_t \frac{1}{T} y_t=0$, with equality if and only if $y_t=0$ for all $t$.
2. Set $y_t = x_t - \mu_x$. Then clearly, $\mu_y=0$, and we have 
   $$ 0=\mu_y \le \sum_t \frac{1}{T} y_t^2= \sum_{t} \frac{1}{T}(x_t - \mu_x)^2=(*)$$

with equality if and only if $0= y_t = x_t -\mu_x$ for all $t$. Expanding, we obtain
 $$(*)=   \sum_{t} \frac{1}{T} (x_t^2 -2 x_t \mu_x + \mu_x^2)=\left(\sum_{t} \frac{1}{T} x_t^2\right)  - 2 \mu_x^2 + \mu_x^2 = \left(\sum \frac{1}{T} x_t^2\right) - \mu_x^2.$$

II. "Probabilistic" proof: same, rewritten in terms of expectations. What difference notation makes.

Let $X$ be a uniform random variable on $\{1,\dots,T\}$. Let $Y=x_T$. This is yet another random variable. We have that

$$ 0 \le E (Y- EY)^2 =E (Y^2 -2Y EY+(EY)^2) = E (Y^2) - 2(EY)^2 + (EY)^2 = E(Y^2)-(EY)^2,$$

By definition, $E Y = \sum \frac{1}{T} x_t$, and $E (Y^2) = \sum \frac{1}{T} x_t^2$.